# Questions tagged with only the tag "untagged"

Tags: support, best-practices, retagging, tags

There are five questions that are tagged with the tag "untagged" I strongly believe that this tag should be removed and the accompanying five questions tagged properly!

Is there a reason why this tag even exists?

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching the meta stackoverflow, apparently this tag "untagged" is used as a temporary state 
[What causes a question to be tagged as [untagged]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167879/what-causes-a-question-to-be-tagged-as-untagged)

Which means that these questions should be dealt with.

Other related questions on meta:

1. [Review task for untagged questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144131/review-task-for-untagged-questions)
2. [Do not allow users to tag questions with "untagged"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122841/do-not-allow-users-to-tag-questions-with-untagged)